# Execute a script in Pentaho DI using an URL

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am new to use this tool.

I am trying to load or execute a script in PHP (http:\.....\re_certification/re_certification.php) in Pentaho. I don't know what tool can I use to be able to do it.

Any idea or example?

Comment: I've never used them myself, but you might have a look at the `REST Client`, 'HTTP Client`, and `Web Services Lookup` steps under the Lookup branch for transforms.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **HTTP Client** step, it will fetch an URL using parameters given - http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/HTTP+Client.

Do not forget that it needs to be triggered - use generate rows or any other input step before this.

There is also a sample at the

```
samples/transformations/HTTP Client - simple retrieval example.ktr
```